# Component parameters between shadcn-ui Card components on the same page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mern, tanstack

I have a page with a table on the left side of a page (built using shadcn/tanstack table). On the right side of the page I want to show the details of whichever row in the table is clicked on.  Both table and details are wrapped in a card (shadcn-ui again).   I can get the relevant 'key' from the clicked row on the table but cannot for the life of me figure out how to render the details on the right.  I already have the data I need in the table so I don't think I need to fetch again from the DB (which is mongodb).  I think I might have to wrap the entire page in a component and somehow pass the table child value back to the parent and then on to the details child....but again can't figure it out.

I am new to the MERN stack so need some help as I can't find anything out there on this particular use case.  What I can find is to pass parameters to an entirely new page but that's not what I want to do.

I have tried to extract the properties from the table (successfully). I need a nudge in the right direction. Is it possible?  Can you pass parameters from child-child components without using the parent?  Can I update the details card without a browser refresh?  Been hours and hours trying to figure this out so any directional help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved this finally using useContext.